# Getting the block relative to a block and relative by the player Direction in Bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

### Getting the block relative to a block and relative by the player Direction in Bukkit

Hello, I am struggling on a Bukkit problem.
So basically, I'm trying to get the block at the right of another. But I want the players to see, in any direction, that the block at the right of the another is at the right of the player too. What I mean is I want the player to see the block at the left of the first block, but FROM the player, not from the server technical locations system.

Since images explain better than just text, here's some images:

Just a normal block
[image: (Image 1)]

The result I except: a new block has been excepted from what the player see to be to the right of the normal block
[image: (Image 2)]

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by getting the direction the player is facing (using the player's `yaw`), and then using that to get the correct block face:

```
Player p;
Block b;

Location l = p.getLocation();
float yaw = l.getYaw();

// Make sure yaw is in the range 0 to 360
while(yaw < 0){yaw+=360;}
yaw = yaw % 360;

// The player's yaw is their rotation in the world,
// so, we can use that to get the right face of a block!
BlockFace rightFace;

// if the player is facing SE to SW
if(yaw < 45 || yaw >= 315){
    rightFace = BlockFace.EAST;
}

// if the player is facing SW to NW
else if(yaw < 135){
    rightFace = BlockFace.SOUTH;
}

// if the player is facing NW to NE
else if(yaw < 225){
    rightFace = BlockFace.WEST;
}

// if the player is facing NE to SE
else if(yaw < 315){
    rightFace = BlockFace.NORTH;
}
```

And now that we know the which BlockFace is on the right of the block, we can get the block on the right:

```
Block b;
BlockFace rightFace;

Block rightBlock = b.getRelative(rightFace);
```

You can also use code that's a lot like this to get the block in front of, behind, or to the left of the block relative to the player — just change what you set `rightFace` to above

I haven't had a chance to test this, but it should work!